# Solr - DataImportHandler clean parameter not working

Tags: solr, lucene, solr4, dataimporthandler, dih

Solr 3.2
As per doc clean parameter is true by default(clean=true,commit=true,optimize=true).

I have 2 cores

- For core-1 index gets deleted once full import is **triggered**
- For core-2 index gets deleted once full import is **completed**.

Why there is difference in behaviour?Anyone faced this issue before?

Comment: How do you know this difference in behaviour? Do you see different results showing up in the middle of the import process with an actual Solr query? Or are you looking at something else?

Comment: Yes,i am trying to get results using solr query.For one core results will start from zero and starts increasing.But for other results will change only after full-import is finished.

Comment: Are you running any other index update operations in a meanwhile? Because the commit in Solr is NOT per-transaction, but for all updates to that point. Then, the other hand could be something to do with old-style replication behaviour. The results would most probably be different in Solr 4.